# Hasmany with child of child in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

I have 3 tables.

1. shops
2. shop_foods
3. foods

I need to fetch foods table data when I create hasmany relation with shops_food and store.

```
$this->hasMany('App\Diet\ShopFood', 'shop_id', 'id');
```

Comment: Show your code and what you have already tried.

Comment: I did $this->hasMany('App\Diet\ShopFood', 'shop_id', 'id'); I got shop_foods data perfetcly  but I also want foods table data under ShopFood array

Answer (score 1):

Please, show your code so we can know what are you trying to do.
But what I can see here is that you have a wrong relationship.

Why are you assigning hasMany in a Many to Many relationship?

In your Shop Model you can make a foods relationship with:

```
$this->belongsToMany('App\Diet\Food);
```

Then you can retreive you food when calling

```
$shop->foods
```

And the shop_foods with the Pivot property

Comment: For shop shop_id is present on shop_food but foods table id is present in  shop_food table.
So I want to fetch all related data from shop model.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you want to get `foods` when you call `shops->shop_foods`. if is that

```
//first you call your shops as you want.
Shop::with(['shops_food' => function($query){
    //the 'shops_food' relationship should be called within an array
    //this way you could query the relationship as the eloquent model.
    //that way you could call the 'foods' relationship inside the shops_food relationship.
    $query->with('foods')
}])
...
```

Note that you must have the relationship declared in shop and shop_foods models

lets your models are like these

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Shop extends Model
{
    //
    public function shops_food()
    {
        //shop_id is the foreing key inside your shop_foods table
        return $this->hasMany('App\ShopFood','shop_id');
    }
    ....
 }
```

then ShopFood Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ShopFood extends Model
{
    //
    public function foods()
    {
        //shop_food_id is the foreing key inside your foods table
        return $this->hasMany('App\Food','shop_food_id');
    }
    ....
 }
```

Comment: I did this as per your comment but unable to fetch the foods data

Comment: please share the shops, shops_food and foods models, and how are you calling them.

Comment: ->with(['StoreMealFood' => function($query) use($foodId) {
                 // $query->on('store_meal_foods.food_id', '=', 'foods.id');
                        $query->where('food_id', "=", $foodId)
                        ->with('Foods');
                               
                    }])
 public function Foods() {    
        return $this->hasMany('App\Diet\Food', 'id', 'food_id');
    }

Comment: Remember you must put the foreing key first then the table key, i edited the answer.

Comment: on the nested with(foods) value is passing null

Comment: under shop_food_table food_id is foreign key

Answer (score 1):

This reads as if you want

```
public function foods() {
    $this->hasMany('App\Diet\Food');
}
```

in your ShopFood model and in your Shop model

```
public function shopfoods() {
    $this->hasMany('App\Diet\ShopFood')->with('foods');
}
```

You can also make 2 separate relations in the Shop model:

```
public function shopfoods() {
    $this->hasMany('App\Diet\ShopFood');
}
public function shopfoodsWithFoods() {
    $this->hasMany('App\Diet\ShopFood')->with('foods');
}
```

So that way you can use whatever you need at that moment.

But the whole thing is really not clear...
I am not even sure how the 3 table are connected, so the hasMany are just guesses.
Nevertheless you can just go with the "with" function.

PS
There is also the possibility to just declare

```
protected $with = ['foods'];
```

in your ShopFood model, if you ALWAYS want those 2 connected. It's all in the documentation.